# Display DynamoDB items in id section of HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-dynamodb

Using a Lambda function, I scan through my db's items. My challenge has been taking those contents, and displaying them as HTML in my <p id=section when a button is clicked. Below are what I have so far.

**HTML code**

```
<p id="all"><b>Show all</b>
    <button onclick="getAll()"><b>Get</b></button>
</p>
```

**Javascript code for getAll()**

```
</script>
    function getAll(itemStr) {
        var itemObj=JSON.parse(itemStr);

        var htm = "";
        var item;
        for (item in itemObj) {
            var data = itemObj[0];
            if (typeof data !== 'object')
                htm += '<li>'+item+' '+itemObj[item] +'</li>';
            else
                htm += '<li>' + item + ' ' + getAll(item) + '</li>';
        }
        return '<ul>'+htm+'</ul>';
    }
</script>
```

**Items put in db by:**

response=dynamodb.put_item(TableName='log', Item={'logID':{'S':str(datetime.now())},'text':{'S':text}})

**DB items returned as**

[{'logID': {'S': '2021-03-23 04:06:46.687457'}, 'text': {'S': "{'chicken':false,'veggie':true,'beef':true,'pork':false,'Take-out':false,'Dine-in':true,'Other':false,'Door-Dash':false}"}},{'logID': {'S': '2021-03-23 02:11:21.440315'}, 'text': {'S': "{'chicken':false,'veggie':true,'beef':false,'pork':false,'Take-out':false,'Dine-in':true,'Other':false,'Door-Dash':false}"}}]

**Screen shots of console.log from XMLHttpRequest**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your example data, you can follow along the code comments below.

```js
//Assumming that data is already an Array, if a string do a JSON.parse first
const itemData = [
  {'logID': {'S': '2021-03-23 04:06:46.687457'}, 
    'text': {'S': "{'chicken':false,'veggie':true,'beef':true,'pork':false,'Take-out':false,'Dine-  in':true,'Other':false,'Door-Dash':false}"}},
  {'logID': {'S': '2021-03-23 02:11:21.440315'}, 
    'text': {'S': "{'chicken':false,'veggie':true,'beef':false,'pork':false,'Take-out':false,'Dine-in':true,'Other':false,'Door-Dash':false}"}}
]


function getAll(itemStr) {
  let htm = ""
  
  
  for (let item of itemStr){
    htm += "<p>Log ID: " + item.logID.S + "</p>" + getAllItems(item.text.S)
  }
  
  //append list to paragraph tag 
  document.getElementById('section').innerHTML = "<ul>" + htm + "</ul>"
  
}


function getAllItems(textData){
  let formattedString = textData.replaceAll(`'`, `"`) // replace all single qoute to double qoutes
  
  //parse textData to JS Object
  let data = JSON.parse(formattedString)
  let listItems = ""
   //loop for displaying data
   for (let key in data) {
      listItems += `<li>${key}:${data[key]}</li>`
   }
   
  return listItems
}

getAll(itemData)
```

```html
<p id="section">
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet, and helping an absolute beginner.  When I ran it, the result is what I wanted to accomplish.  However, I may have missed a couple of things. 1. I get my db items using XMLHttpRequest().  Therefore, using your example, I did an assignment, const itemData = this.responseText, and 2.  I then passed itemData as getAllItems(itemData).  Since .replaceAll(), was not recognized as a valid function, I changed it to .replace(/'/g, '"'). However, I am now getting an invalid function for textData.replace(/'/g, '"').  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What does the response look like, is it a string or a JSON object, can you provide an output by console.log() then a screenshot.

Comment: Attached screen shots of console.log response.

Comment: I didn't realize that I should have passed itemData as getAll(itemsData) instead of getAllItems(itemData).  However, I now get the dev console message. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'S' of undefined" in getAll's "htm += "<p>Log ID: " + item.logID.S...".  I'm new to this dot notation in javascript, and thought it made sense from how items were put in the db (shown in "Items put in db by" section above).

Comment: Also, I don't understand the getAll(itemData) at very bottom of the code snippet. What is it supposed to do? Why is it in that location?

Comment: 1. seems that itemData are string, it need to be JSON.parse first, as I mentioned on the above code comment.
2. It's calling the function, it's standard on most programming language to put function call after the function, although Javascript is unlike most programming language, Javascript has something called hoisting where you can put function call before the function but it's not always the case, more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: Thanks, John.  Your snippet guided me tremendous.